# Is there any limitation to copy data from Device to Host?

Tags: c, cuda

I am trying to copy around 8650752 bytes from device to host but i am getting stack overflow error , surprisingly i can copy same data from Host to Device but after computing on it ,not able to get back. code is pretty simple so not sure whats wrong

Code:

```
__global__ 
void kernel(....)
{
    int x=threadIDX.x;

    for (int j=0; j<256; j++)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
        { 
            int index = 256*256*x + 256*j + i;      
            dVOL_in[(x*65536)+(256*j)+i]=index;
        }
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    const int VOL_SIZE = 8650752;                           
    const int VOL_BYTES = VOL_SIZE * sizeof(float);
    float hVOL[VOL_SIZE];
    float * dVOL_in;

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**) &dVOL_in, VOL_BYTES));

    // volume data read from some file
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemset(dVOL_in,0,VOL_BYTES));  
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(dVOL_in,Vol,VOL_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));  //works fine

    kernel<<<1,132>>>(....);
    cudaMemcpy(hVOL, dVOL_in, VOL_BYTES, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  //stack overflow error
}
```

Comment: The `hVOL` array is 33 MB. The kernel probably doesn't have that much stack space.

Comment: So create your host array `hVOL` with `malloc` instead.

Comment: If you plan on asking more questions here, please get in the habit of formatting you code so it is easy for those trying to help you to read it. This was just awful.....

Comment: @talonmies I apologize .i will make sure i do proper formatting next time onward.

Comment: I added the "c" tag since the error here has nothing to do with CUDA...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When defined in the function body, as a local variable:

```
int main(void)
{
   const int VOL_SIZE = 8650752;
   float hVOL[VOL_SIZE];
```

the compiler will allocate the object `hVol` in the stack. But this object does not fit into the maximum stack size so you get this error. For such large objects, you need to allocate the memory dynamically:

```
   float *hVOL = malloc(sizeof(float) * VOL_SIZE);
```